# Unable to ping one service to another service in Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service

I have created a local ubuntu Kubernetes cluster,  having 1 master and 2 slave nodes.

I deployed 2 applications in 2 pods and created service for both of the pods, it's working fine.
I entered inside pod by typing this command ,

```
$ kubectl exec -it firstpod /bin/bash
# apt-get update
```

Unable to make update and I'm getting an error:

```
Err http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease

Err http://deb.debian.org jessie InRelease

Err http://deb.debian.org jessie-updates InRelease

Err http://security.debian.org jessie/updates Release.gpg   Temporary failure resolving 'security.debian.org' Err http://deb.debian.org jessie-backports InRelease

Err http://deb.debian.org jessie Release.gpg   Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org' Err http://deb.debian.org jessie-updates Release.gpg   Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org' Err http://deb.debian.org jessie-backports Release.gpg   Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org' Reading package lists... Done W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie/InRelease

W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/InRelease

W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/jessie/updates/InRelease

W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-backports/InRelease

W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/jessie/updates/Release.gpg  Temporary failure resolving 'security.debian.org'

W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie/Release.gpg  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'

W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/Release.gpg  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'

W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-backports/Release.gpg  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I'm trying to ping my second pod service:

```
# ping secondservice (This is the service name of secondpod)
PING secondservice.default.svc.cluster.local (10.100.190.196): 56 data bytes
unable to ping.
```

How can I ping/call the second service from the first node?

Comment: Did you install pod network (calico/flannel.. etc) in your cluster? Also can you please check the `kube-proxy` pod's log?

Comment: Looks like you don't have any network...

Comment: ys I have install flannel network ,and all the system pods are working fine .This is the logs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two (unrelated) questions I see there. I'm going to focus on the second one since the first is unclear to me (what is the ask?).

So, you wonder why the following doesn't work:

```
# ping secondservice
```

This is not a bug or unexpected (actually, I wrote about it [here](https://blog.openshift.com/kubernetes-services-by-example/)). In short: the FQDN `secondservice.default.svc.cluster.local` gets resolved via the DNS plugin to a virtual IP ([VIP](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#virtual-ips-and-service-proxies)), the very essence of this VIP is that it is virtual, that is, it's not attached to a network interface, it's just a bunch of iptables rules. Hence, the ICMP-based ping has nothing to work against, since it's not a 'real' IP. You can `curl` the service, though. Assuming the service runs on port 9876, the following should work:

```
# curl secondservice:9876
```

Comment: Hi Michael ,there are 2 pods first and second and service firstservice and secondservice repectively .now I am in firstpod by typing command : kubectl exec -it firstpod /bin/bash .From here I am typing your curl command curl secondservice:3011 .but the output showing nothing .is this correct or is there other way .

Comment: Since I don't know your app I don't know what the expected output is. What do you mean with "showing nothing"? Do a `curl -v` and update your question with the output, please.

Comment: Hi, I've understood that by default we can't Ping a k8s service, but is there anyway I can configure the Service, as to forward that ICMP request to a physical pod? I know I can use curl to test the connectivity, but in my use-case it would be beneficial to have both TCP and ICMP messages. Do you know if that would be possible?